# what do they mean when they say so?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology

> DevOps aligns with iterative and agile project development models.

I am trying to understand what are they really saying. iterative is repeating but still I am not able to catch the real meaning in this sentence. Agile project methodology is more flexible and is eliminating the silos but not sure what do they mean by iterative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the same process will be applied over and over again (repeatedly, iteratively). You build a flexible development process (usually with 4-5 well-defined steps) and then constantly repeat it.

Comment: so they most likely mean the process will be applied over and over again with the agile methodology ?

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby It's not saying that DevOps combines the two, just that it has commonalities with the two approaches to development.

Answer (score 2):

[Iterative development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) is a software development model that was trendy before agile. It was, itself, intended as a contrast to [waterfall development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model). It is, essentially, the idea that you don't design something and implement it, but keep designing, evaluating and re-specifying as you go. It works well with the idea that deployment is not the end of the process, though you can have that with waterfall as well - you just go back to the top of the waterfall after deployment.

Agile is really, to my mind, a refinement and extension of iterative development. It specifies that iteration in the form of frequent prototype and semi-functional deployments and ongoing contact with clients.

Now, the quote says that DevOps **aligns with** these two development models. That doesn't necessarily mean that it *combines* both. [DevOps is *another* development model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps), and that statement is saying that it has fundamental points in common with agile and iterative methods. Basically, if you like or can do iterative or agile, then you'll fit into a DevOps workplace without too much trouble. *That* is what it is saying.